# How can I suppress zsh pattern escaping during string expansion?

Tags: zsh, string-matching, variable-expansion

I am trying to port this snippet of code from `bash` to `zsh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash  # change zsh

set -x

pattern="[ab]"
marks="a"

case "${marks}" in
   ${pattern})
      echo match
   ;;
esac
```

This prints "match".

**Bash** replaces `${pattern}` as is and then uses `[ab]` to match either `'a'` or `'b'`.

**zsh** seemingly escapes the `'[]'` characters and then uses `\[ab\]` to match this string verbatim.

I don't see a zsh option, how to change the behavior and hardcoding the pattern is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `zsh` treat a parameter value as a pattern, instead of a literal string, you need to use [glob substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```
local marks=a pattern='[ab]'

case $marks in
   ( $~pattern )
      echo match
   ;;
esac
```